# CSS, How can I make this image animation not come back and instead go over and around the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

It's my first time animating something on css and I want to make a similar effect to the one on fishao.com, how the clouds move around, go beyond the page and then they return, my animation goes to the end of the page then comes backwards then goes again to the end, it doesn't really go like in a transition, idk how to explain, plz help. (been coding for 3 weeks)

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 100vh;
  height: 10%;
  width: 11%;
  animation: Cloudanim 50s linear infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes Cloudanim {
  0% {
    left: 100vh;
  }
  25% {
    left: 50vh;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0vh;
  }
  75% {
    left: 165vh;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Cartoon_cloud.svg">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a continuous animation where the image goes over and around the page without coming back abruptly, you can modify your CSS and animation keyframes as follows:

```
img {
  position: absolute; /* Change from 'relative' to 'absolute' */
  top: 80px;
  left: -10%; /* Start the image outside the left edge of the page */
  height: 10%;
  width: 11%;
  animation: Cloudanim 50s linear infinite; /* Remove 'forwards' property */
}

@keyframes Cloudanim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-10%); /* Use 'transform' instead of 'left' */
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(40%); /* Adjust the distances as needed */
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(90%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(140%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(190%); /* Adjust the distance to complete the loop */
  }
}
```

**More to be sure :**

1. Change the position of the image to absolute so that it can move freely around the page.
2. Adjust the initial left value to place the image outside the left edge of the page (-10%).
3. Remove the forwards property from the animation so that it repeats smoothly without reversing.
4. Instead of animating the left property, use the transform property with translateX() to move the image horizontally. This gives better performance and avoids layout recalculations.
5. Adjust the distances in the translateX() values to control the movement of the image. Positive values move the image to the right, and negative values move it to the left.